# ¿ Cómo ejecutar un script de Javascript a través de NVIM?

Tags: javascript, linux, script, debian, vim

Estoy aprendiendo a usar nvim, mi pregunta es, después de haber escrito mi código en javascript, cómo puedo ejecutarlo mediante una consola en nvim ? mi sistema operativo es debian.

Comment: Para ejecutar tu archivo abierto actual puedes utilizar `!%`

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto con !% me aparece lo siguiente:                            :!prueba.js                                                             
/bin/bash: prueba.js: orden no encontrada

El intérprete de órdenes devolvió 127

Pulse INTRO o escriba una orden para continuar

Comment: Si tienes Node.js instalado: `:! node %`

Comment: Ya publiqué la respuesta, pero no te preocupes, lo importante es que te funcionara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo instalado Node.js, para ejecutar tu archivo abierto actual puedes utilizar:

```
:! node %
```

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó !!